# Set option-html disabled if j = 0

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-select, angular-ng-if

Is it possible to set select option `disabled`, if the value is `j = 0` ?
The j value is taken from a DB.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let interventi of variabileIntervento; index as i">
           <tr *ngFor="let variante of interventi.varianti; index as j">
             <td><select [(ngModel)]="type" (change)="changeTotal()">
               <option selected disabled>Select</option>  
               <option value="0">{{interventi.supIntonacate[j]}}</option>
               <option value="1">{{interventi.supEvIi[j]}}</option>
               <option value="2">{{interventi.supIvEi[j]}}</option></select></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<option selected [disabled]="j === 0 ? true : false">Select</option>
```

or this, if not work:

```
<option selected [attr.disabled]="j === 0 ? 'disabled' : null">Select<option>
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#property-and-attribute-comparison